# Tizen app : gear current consumption is too high on sleep mode

Tags: sensors, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have an application in Tizen in which I am recording the sensor data of some activity of a user. The application is hybrid type and the accelerometer, gyroscope data is registered in the native service application. 
I have an option where the user can pause the recording of data. When the device goes to is paused, `sensor_listener_unset_event_cb(listener_accelero)` and `device_power_release_lock(POWER_LOCK_CPU)` are called. Hence, it is expected that no sensor data will be received while in sleep state.

However, on submitting to Tizen store I get the following rejection message :

```
[CURRENT] Gear current consumption is too high on sleep mode
- Tested application
Min current: 23.1 mA, Average current: 24.173 mA
- Samsung Gear standard current consumption
Min current: 4 mA, Average current: 7 mA
```

The video attachment shows that reported current consumption is in sleep state after pausing the recording. What could be the reason for such high current drawn? Also, how can I verify whether some tweak actually solves the problem. Is there any application which does the current/power profiling for Samsung gear S2/S3?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping app awake in device screen off state is sensitive issue. Have you tried using SENSOR_OPTION_ALWAYS_ON

```
sensor_listener_set_option(listener, SENSOR_OPTION_ALWAYS_ON);
```

[Sensor API: Sensor option](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#gaf517b61e58b872f985fc2fc2a26aa56a)

You may also see this links:

[Allowing Applications to Run on the Background](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#gaf517b61e58b872f985fc2fc2a26aa56a)

[Tizen accelerometer sensor usage](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/tizen-accelerometer-sensor-usage?langredirect=1)

Stop the sensor listeners when the app is going to pause state. Then again start the listeners when app is up front again if necessary.

[sensor_listener_stop   ( listener  )](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#gacb033320d99462e766ba5454c2612a34)

Comment: Hi there, I have included the option in my native application for both gyroscope and accelerometer sensors. However, my problem is not that I want to receive data in sleep mode, but I want to know why the current consumption in sleep mode is high even though data is not received (paused).

Comment: Even when you are using sensor_listener_unset_event_cb(listener_accelero) and device_power_release_lock(POWER_LOCK_CPU) at the moment device is going to pause state the power consumption is high in sleep mode?

Comment: Yes, this is what the video sent along with the rejection report says. I am not able to understand what could be the reason for this or how I could resolve this

Comment: Edited@Manish Sharma